# Search ListView with Custom Adapter, shows no results and does not crash program

Tags: android, listview, search, adapter

I am trying to implement a search function on a ListView that is using a custom adapter. I am following this example:http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=149.  I was able to edit the code and put it in my adapter. However, it is not bring up any results. Can you look over my code and let me know what I missed or is there something else I can do?

Here is the listView:

```
public class DataView extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private static final String rssFeed = "http://leobee.com/android/push/login/schedule.php";
private static final String AddEvent = "http://leobee.com/android/push/login/deleteUpdate.php";

private static final String ARRAY_NAME = "events";
private static final String EVENT_NAME = "event_name";
private static final String EVENT_ID = "event_id";
private static final String EVENT_DATE = "event_date";
private static final String EVENT_START = "event_start";
private static final String EVENT_END = "event_end";
private static final String EVENT_LOCATION = "event_location";
private static final String EVENT_DELETE_FLAG = "event_delete_flag";

List<Item> arrayOfList;
List<String> sortOfList;
  SimpleAdapter simpleadapter;

ListView listView;
NewsRowAdapter objAdapter;
List<Integer> deleteList;
String undelete;
String eventNameDeleted;
String eventIdDeleted;
String eventDateDeleted;
String eventStartDeleted;
String eventEndDeleted;
String eventLocationDeleted;
JSONObject json;
String addBack = "0";
Button btnMessage;
Button btnLogout;
UserFunctions userFunctions;
EditText searchBox;
int textlength = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedulelistview);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.isTextFilterEnabled();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        deleteList = new ArrayList<Integer>();      
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMessage);
        searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);




        arrayOfList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(DataView.this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
        } else {
            showToast("No Network Connection. Application is unable to load data.");
        }

    } else {



    }



}



class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DataView.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Item objItem = new Item();

                    // here objItem is reciveing and processing data from
                    // JSON string text
                    objItem.setId(objJson.getInt(EVENT_ID));// names from
                    objItem.setName(objJson.getString(EVENT_NAME));
                    objItem.setDate(objJson.getString(EVENT_DATE));
                    objItem.setDeleteFlag(objJson.getInt(EVENT_DELETE_FLAG));

                    arrayOfList.add(objItem);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {

                Item deletflagCheck = arrayOfList.get(i);

                if (deletflagCheck.getDeleteFlag() == 1) {

                    deleteList.add(deletflagCheck.getId());
                } else {

                }

            }

        }
        setAdapterToListview();

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewDel, int position,
        long id) {

    Item deletflagCheck = arrayOfList.get(position);

    if (deletflagCheck.getDeleteFlag() == 1) {

        showDeleteDialog(position);

    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(DataView.this.getApplicationContext(),
                UpdateServer.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Item item = arrayOfList.get(position);
            intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
            intent.putExtra("name", item.getName());
            intent.putExtra("date", item.getDate());
            intent.putExtra("startTime", item.getStartTime());
            intent.putExtra("endTime", item.getEndTime());
            intent.putExtra("location", item.getLocation());
            intent.putExtra("deleteFlag", item.getDeleteFlag());

        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}


public void setAdapterToListview() {

    objAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(DataView.this,
            R.layout.schedulelistrow, arrayOfList, deleteList);
    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);



    searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                objAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

        });






}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(DataView.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String location;
    private int deleteFlag;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getDeleteFlag() {
        return deleteFlag;
    }

    public void setDeleteFlag(int deleteFlag) {
        this.deleteFlag = deleteFlag;
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<Item> items;
    private Item objBean;
    private int row;
    private List<Integer> disable;
    View view ;
    int disableView;
    ListFilter  filter ;
    List<Item> filteredItems;

    public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList, List<Integer> disableList) {
        super(act, resource, arrayList);
        this.activity = act;
        this.row = resource;
        this.items = arrayList;
         filteredItems = items;
        this.disable=disableList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();        
    }
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        for(int k =0;k < disable.size();k++){
            if(position==disable.get(k)){

                disableView=disable.get(k);
                System.out.println("disagle view at" +disableView);

            } 

        }


    return position;
}

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

                    getItemViewType(position);

                    if(position==disableView){ 
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                        }else{
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                        }


                    //ViewHolder is a custom class that gets TextViews by name: tvName, tvCity, tvBDate, tvGender, tvAge;
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    /* setTag Sets the tag associated with this view. A tag can be used to
                     *  mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique 
                     *  within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within
                     *   a view without resorting to another data structure.

        */
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {

                    getItemViewType(position);

                    if(position==disableView){ 
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


                        }else{
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                        }

                    //the Object stored in this view as a tag
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
                    return view;

                objBean = items.get(position);


        holder.tv_event_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_name);
        holder.tv_event_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_date);
        holder.tv_event_start = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_start);
        holder.tv_event_end = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_end);
        holder.tv_event_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_location);


        if (holder.tv_event_name != null && null != objBean.getName()
                && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tv_event_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));

        }
        if (holder.tv_event_date != null && null != objBean.getDate()
                && objBean.getDate().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tv_event_date.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getDate()));
        }
        if (holder.tv_event_start != null && null != objBean.getStartTime()
                && objBean.getStartTime().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tv_event_start.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getStartTime()));
        }
        if (holder.tv_event_end != null && null != objBean.getEndTime()
                && objBean.getEndTime().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tv_event_end.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getEndTime()));
        }
        if (holder.tv_event_location != null && null != objBean.getLocation ()
                && objBean.getLocation ().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tv_event_location.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getLocation ()));

        }


        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView 
        tv_event_name,
        tv_event_date,
        tv_event_start,
        tv_event_end,
        tv_event_location
        /*tv_event_delete_flag*/;


    }

    private class ListFilter extends Filter{

        List<Item> filt;
        List<Item> tmpItems;


        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults retval = new FilterResults();
            List<Item> filt;
            List<Item> tmpItems;
            retval.values = items;
                        retval.count = items.size();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                                 filt = new ArrayList<Item>();
                                 tmpItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
                                tmpItems.addAll(items);
                                for(int i = 0; i > tmpItems.size(); i++) {
                                    Item sf = tmpItems.get(i);
                                    if(sf.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                                        filt.add(sf);
                                    }
                                }
                               retval.count = filt.size();
                               retval.values = filt;
                           }
                      return retval;
            }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {


            filteredItems = (ArrayList)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();

            for (int i = 0; i> filteredItems.size(); i++){
                add(filteredItems.get(i));
            }
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }       

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter = new ListFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

}
```

The xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="Logout" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:text="Send Message To All" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```